# Meaning of 自分で呼んどいて

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, verbs

Context: two guys have just finished discussing a matter.

> Character A: 俺の話そんなとこだ。あー疲れた。おまえ伊吹【いぶき】のとこ帰れ。 (pushing character B)
>
> Character B: 自分で呼んどいて！ (looking irritated, then goes away)

I understand that 呼んどいて is a contraction of 呼んでおいて, but I still don't understand the meaning of the second sentence.

Since it finishes in -て form, I suppose Character B is telling Character A to do something, but the meaning of 呼ぶ is not clear to me here. Is it being used with the meaning of "to tell" rather than "to call"? Not being able to understand the meaning of 呼ぶ, I don't understand the value of おく either.

Judging from the context, could the translation be something like "Mind yor own business" or "You don't need to tell me that"? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, 「呼んどいて」 is a colloquial contraction of 「呼んでおいて」.

> 「自分{じぶん}で + Verb in te-from + おいて」

is a common expression meaning:

> "I/you/(s)he am/are/is the one who (verb + ed), **but (now)** ~~~~"
>
> "It was I/you/(s)he who (verb + ed), **but (now)** ~~~~"

***The entire main clause (the ~~~~ part) is sometimes left unsaid*** and that is the key factor to this expression.

Also of importance is the fact that who 「自分」 refers to depends entirely on the context.

> 「自分で呼{よ}んどいて」

thus means in that context:

> "***It was you who called me over (, but you are now telling me to go home)***."

Comment: So, the reason why the coordinative -て form is used instead of the past -た form, is that there's a main clause left unsaid, right?